# Bootstrap two sections one overlapping image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to make this design. I was wondering the best approach to have an inline image span two sections with background images.

[image]

It will obviously be responsive.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your current markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by creating 3 divs and container for them and give position relative for container and for 3rd div give position as absolute.
Code:

```
       .box_1 {
            background-color: #c1c1c1;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .box_2 {
            background-color: #cc0000;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .box_3 {
            background-color: #000;
            display: block;
            height: 100px;
            left: 42%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            width: 50px;
        }
        .box_container {
            position: relative;
        }
[Working example][1]https://jsfiddle.net/4c22acc0/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! appreciated!